# Update listView dynamically with updated json data

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am retrieving json from server to sqlite and then populating my listView. Used customCursorAdpater.
My question is: if new objects are added to the json in the future, then how to retrieve only those objects to sqlite table and update the listview. I really dont have any answer for this. Please help me out.

```
[{ 
    "Sermons Youtube ID" : "xxxxx",
    "Speaker" : "xxxxx",
    "node_title" : "xxxxxx",
    "Video_Length" : "xxxxx",
    "Image_Thumbnail" : "xxxx.png"
},
{
    "Sermons Youtube ID" : "xxxxx",
    "Speaker" : "xxxxx",
    "node_title" : "xxxxxx",
    "Video_Length" : "xxxxx",
    "Image_Thumbnail" : "xxxx.png"
},
{
    "Sermons Youtube ID" : "xxxxx",
    "Speaker" : "xxxxx",
    "node_title" : "xxxxxx",
    "Video_Length" : "xxxxx",
    "Image_Thumbnail" : "xxxx.png"
},
{
    "Sermons Youtube ID" : "xxxxx",
    "Speaker" : "xxxxx",
    "node_title" : "xxxxxx",
    "Video_Length" : "xxxxx",
    "Image_Thumbnail" : "xxxx.png"
}]
```

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Comment: sync adapters is the good idea, but where is the good example?